# Simple IF statement with more than 1 digit numbers?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Below I'm testing a simple IF statement but it doesn't seem to take the whole number I'm comparing in to account. You can see this number is greater than "2", but with my result it's like it's only reading the "1" and that's it, so telling me the number is "Less or Equal" than "2", I would expect the result "LARGE" to be returned. How can I get it to read the whole number and not just the first digit?

```
IF "1073740972" LEQ "2" (
    ECHO LESS or EQU 2 
        ) ELSE (
    ECHO LARGE
)
```

The "LARGE" number is an %ERRORLEVEL% generated number so this can be different each time.

I have tried Changing [LEQ "2"] to [LSS "3"] but I do not know what else I could try.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks from the comparison expressions:

```
IF 1073740972 LEQ 2 (
    ECHO LESS or EQU 2 
        ) ELSE (
    ECHO LARGE
)
```

Otherwise, no numeric but string comparison is performed, where the character codes are regarded, so character `1` (ASCII `49` = `0x31`) is less than character `2` (ASCII `50`= `0x32`).